# Puppeteer - prevent reloading when connecting to a running browser

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to connect to a running chromium instance on a remote device with a touchscreen. However, this causes a reload of the webapp and losing it's current state.

```
  const connectOpts = {
    browserURL: 'http://remote-host:4321',
    defaultViewport: {
      width: 1024,
      height: 600,
      hasTouch: true  // works fine if removed
    }
  };

  const browser = await puppeteer.connect(connectOpts);

  try {
    // this causes a reload
    const pages = await browser.pages();

    // this wouldn't cause a reload
    //const contexts = await browser.browserContexts();
    //const pages = await contexts.pages();
  }
  finally {
    await browser.disconnect();
  }
```

This seems related to the touch display, when I remove the hasTouch property it works as expected. It also works as long as I don't call either browser.pages() or browserContext.pages(). Is there any way to access the page and prevent the reload to preserve the app's original state while also having touch enabled?